# Consuming an Array returned from a Method

Tags: c#

from my function below, I am returning an array. In C# how would I consume that array?

```
 public Array arrayFucntion()
 {
// do something

 foreach (var Objs in items)
            {



                list.Add(Objs.value1);


            }

            string[] myArray = list.ToArray();
            MessageBox.Show(myArray.ToString());
            return myArray;
}
```

Now how would I use it in a function like below

```
void consumeFunction()
        {

            var x = arrayFucntion();

       // what do do to see values of the array


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a string[],  then you can do the for loop through the string array.

```
public string[]arrayFucntion()

void consumeFunction()
{
  var x = arrayFucntion();
  for (int i=0; i<x.Lenght; i++)
  {       
    x[i]...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the return type `string[]` instead of `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the members:

```
foreach (string sArrayMember in x)
{
   // Do something with s
}
```

You can also access any of the properties or members listed in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), including Copy, Find, and Sort.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is now an `array object`...

you can do `foreach` on it, or use `linq`.....or using direct addressing `x[0]`